# First experience of using interfaces in C#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, interface

I have an interface:

```
interface ISqlite
    {

         void insert();

         void update();

         void delete();

         void select();
    }
```

And custom service class:

```
class SqliteService
    {
        public SQLiteDatabase driver;

        public SqliteService() {

            SqliteConnection(new SQLiteDatabase());
        }

        public void SqliteConnection(SQLiteDatabase driver)
        {
            this.driver = driver;
        }

        public void select(ISqlite select) {

            select.select();
        }


        public void insert(ISqlite insert) {

            insert.insert();

        }

        public void delete(ISqlite delete)
        {

            delete.delete();

        }
    }
```

And last class `Pacients` that realizes ISqlite interface:

```
class Pacients: ISqlite
    {

        public List<ClientJson> pacients;

        public Pacients() {

            this.pacients = new List<ClientJson>();
        }

        public void add(ClientJson data) {

            this.pacients.Add(data);
        }

        public void insert()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        /* Others methos from interface */
}
```

I try to use my code like as:

```
/* Create instance of service class */
SqliteService serviceSqlite = new SqliteService();

/* Create instance of class */
Pacients pacient = new Pacients();

pacient.add(client);
serviceSqlite.insert(pacient);
```

As you can see above I send object `pacient` that realizes interface `ISqlite` to service. It means that will be called method `insert` from object `pacient`.

Problem is that I dont understand how to add data in this method using external class: `SQLiteDatabase()`? How to get access to `this.driver` in service class from object `pacient`?

**Edit 1**

I think I must move instance of connection `new SQLiteDatabase()` to db inside `Pacients` class is not it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the signature of interface's methods to pass an `SQLiteDatabase` object.

```
interface ISqlite
{
     void insert(SQLiteDatabase driver);
     void update(SQLiteDatabase driver);
     void delete(SQLiteDatabase driver);
     void select(SQLiteDatabase driver);
}
```

Example call from the service:

```
public void insert(ISqlite insert) 
{
    insert.insert(driver);
}
```

I think you can figure out the rest by yourself.

Comment: I am not sure that I did it right, do  you see something wrong in my solution?

Comment: @ITMANAGER Well, you wanted to use the driver from the `ISqlite` instance, so I gave you a possible solution for that :-)

Comment: I think it is not good, when we have strong dependency from object `SQLiteDatabase` in class `Paicents`

Comment: If `SQLiteDatabase` implements an interface, then modify the code to use the abstraction if you want to. I am not familiar with this API.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, I would favor a solution where the data objects themselves don't know anything about how they're stored, i.e. they have no knowledge of the class that communicates with the database. Many ORMs do just that.

Of course it might not be easy depending on the specifics of your situation... Try to examine what your methods on each object actually need; generally speaking they need the values of properties, and what column each property corresponds to, right? So any external class can do this if it knows these bits of information. You can specify the name of the column with a custom attribute on each property (and if the attribute isn't there, the column must have the same name as the property).

And again, this is the most basic thing that ORMs (Object Relational Mappers) do, and in addition they also manage more complicated things like relationships between objects/tables. I'm sure there are many ORMs that work with SqlLite. If you're OK with taking the time to learn the specifics of an ORM, that's what I would recommend using - although they're not silver bullets and will never satisfy all possible requirements, they are in my opinion perfect for automating the most common day to day things.

More to the point of the question, you can of course make it work like that if you pass the SQLiteDatabase object to the methods, or keep it in a private field and require it in the constructor or otherwise make sure that it's available when you need it; there's no other simple solution I can think of. And like you pointed out, it implies a certain degree of coupling.